# Does QML support state inheritance & overriding?

Tags: qt4, qml

I have a `CoolButton` which have a `pressed` state:

```
// CoolButton.qml:
BorderImage {
    ...
    states: State {
        name: "pressed"
        when: mouseArea.pressed == true
        PropertyChanges { target: shade; opacity: 0.5 }
    }
}
```

And the `MenuButton` extends `CoolButton`:

```
// MenuButton.qml:
CoolButton {
    ...
    states: State {
        name: "pressed"
        PropertyChanges { ... }
    }
}
```

However, the `pressed` state defined in the `MenuButton` seems not work at all. Is it hidden by the `pressed` state defined in the `CoolButton`? And how can I override it?

Should it be something like this?

```
// MenuButton.qml:
CoolButton {
    ...
    states: State {
        name: "pressed"
        extend: "CoolButton.pressed"
        PropertyChanges { ... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am new to QML, but as far as I know you can't extend or override defined components.
Instead you can encapsulate them, something like this:

```
// CoolButton.qml:
BorderImage {
    ...
    states: State {
        name: "pressed"
        when: mouseArea.pressed == true
        PropertyChanges { target: shade; opacity: 0.5 }
    }
}
```

and encapsulation can look like this:

```
// MenuButton.qml:
CoolButton {
    property alias cb: encapsulatedCB
    CoolButton {id: encapsulatedCB; }
    ...

    states: State {
        name: "pressed"
        PropertyChanges { ... }
    }
}
```